# arangodb and spring data, how can I use a user generated Id?

Tags: java, spring-data, arangodb

I'm using ArangoDB arangodb-java-driver.version=4.2.1 and arangodb-spring-data.version=1.1.2 (although will be moving to spring boot 2 soon, so these will change)

I would like to be able create new objects with an id that's already generated.

I realize this can be done using the arangoTemplate/arangoOperations (`arangoOperations.insert(doc)`) but this takes us out of spring data and pulls arango specific code into my service classes.

The issue is that if I save a new object that already contains an id (that uses the @Id annotation) then arango will assume it's an update, and fail with object-not-found (as it checks to see if the object is there before doing an update)

So ... does anyone have any bright ideas that will help me to use arangodb *and* spring data *and* provide my own IDs ?

thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: How is this idea not a disaster in the making? I’ve never seen meaningful ids (why else have them be user generated) lead to anything but pain and suffering.

Comment: @Scary: would you make user email address a primary key?

Comment: @NathanHughes oops misread that

Comment: There are a couple of use-cases where it's needed, one example is when a client provides UUIDs for objects that were created before even sending to the server.  Another involves pulling in records from other systems - where the same id is needed.
But certainly - pain and suffering is just inches away ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is currently an issue and the only workaround I see, is to use a field annotated with `@Key` and use `ArangoOperations.insert(Object)` to initial save your entity.

Solving this problem is on high priority. I created a [github issue](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/issues/81) to track the progress on this.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have used that insert method for now. (I'd vote up but don't have enough reputation points)